# Making a Caesar Cypher, and it does not want to decipher the message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

For a project, we have to make a Caesar Cipher using classes and save the encrypted message inside of a file so a user can decipher it with the program.

I input the message and it has no problem encrypting the message according to the displacement/key I input (since I gave an option for the user to place the displacement they please).

However, the problem lies in decripting the message. It seems to only decript the penultimate or last letter of what I inputted and it doesnt even bother to show the remaining characters of the message.

I have currently no idea why its acting the way it is, I figured I would have to change the message to take char variables instead of string, but that would mean rewriting a large chunk of the code, and at the moment, I would like to avoid having to rewrite the code from scratch.  If there are no other options, then I guess I will have to rewrite the code.

Here is the code, (hope that helps and sorry if my message may seem messy, this is the first time I post anything here):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>

/* This is a program that will grab a message from the user and encrypt it, then decrypt it 
    It will also generate a random 8-digit character password used to access the encrypted file
    It will also have the ability to allow the user to choose how many spaces the cipher will take into account */

using namespace std;

//Implement a set displacement and get displacement

class Cipherer
{
private:
    int displacement;
    string message;
    //string decryptMessage;

public:
    void setDisplacer(int key);
    int getDisplacer()const;
    void msgEncripter(string, int);
    string getMessage()const;
    void msgDecripter(string);
    string getDecription()const;
};

void Cipherer::setDisplacer(int key)
{
    displacement = key;
}
int Cipherer::getDisplacer()const
{
    return displacement;
}
void Cipherer::msgEncripter(string msg, int key)
{
    string encriptedMsg = msg;
    //.size returns the number of elements
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < msg.size(); i++)
    {
        if (msg[i] == 32) //32 is the value in ASCII of the space character
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((msg[i] + key) > 122)
            {
                int temp = (msg[i] + key) - 122;
                encriptedMsg[i] = 96 + temp;
            }
            else if (msg[i] + key > 90 && msg[i] <= 96)
            {
                int temp = (msg[i] + key) - 90;
                encriptedMsg[i] = 64 + temp;
            }
            else
            {
                encriptedMsg[i] += key;
            }
        }
    }
    message = encriptedMsg;
}
string Cipherer::getMessage()const
{
    return message;
}
void Cipherer::msgDecripter(string msg)
{
    string decriptedMsg;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < msg.size(); i++)
    {
        if (msg[i] == 32)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((msg[i] - displacement) < 97 && (msg[i] - displacement) > 90)
            {
                decriptedMsg[i] = (msg[i] - displacement) + 26;
            }
            else if ((msg[i] - displacement) < 65)
            {
                decriptedMsg[i] = (msg[i] - displacement) + 26;
            }
            else
            {
                decriptedMsg = msg[i] - displacement;
            }
        }
    }
    message = decriptedMsg;
}
string Cipherer::getDecription()const
{
    return message;
}

static const char PASSWORD_POOL[] =
"0123456789";

int poolSize = sizeof(PASSWORD_POOL) - 1;

char getRandChar()
{
    return PASSWORD_POOL[rand() % poolSize];
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    string pass, input, msg;
    int key;
    Cipherer message;
    ofstream outputFile;
    ifstream inputFile;
    outputFile.open("SecretMSG.txt");
    cout << "Write a message: \n";
    getline(cin, msg);
    cout << "Choose the displacement of the message (0-25): ";
    cin >> key;
    message.setDisplacer(key);
    message.msgEncripter(msg, key);
    outputFile << msg;
    outputFile.close();
    for (int count = 0; count < 1; count++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            pass += getRandChar();
        }
        cout << pass << endl;
    }
    cout << "Input password " << pass << " ";
    cin >> input;
    if (input == pass)
    {
        //Make a local variable to read file 
        string encryptedMessage;
        inputFile.open("SecretMSG.txt");
        inputFile >> encryptedMessage;
        inputFile.close();

        cout << message.getMessage() << endl;
        cout << "If you wish to decrypt the message, type in the password once again " << pass << ": ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input == pass)
        {
            message.msgDecripter(encryptedMessage);
            cout << message.getDecription() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: My one piece of advice is to avoid magic numbers. like 65, 122 ... instead use 'A' and 'z'. This probably won't help you fix the issue but will make you a better programmer. Readability of code is extremely important especially if you would ever get a job as a software developer.

Comment: To solve this problem you need to use your debugger. Step through the code 1 line at a time looking at the variables at each step. Try to figure out how your algorithm deviates from your expectation. Try a short string as an example first.

Comment: Another hint that is unrelated to your problem: You should pass strings as `const std::string &` if you don't intend to copy the string. For example `void Cipherer::msgDecripter(const std::string &msg)`

Comment: @churill passing by const ref is not necessarily better then passing by a const value. Especially if you frequently read from it in the function.

Comment: @Subs103017 what is `now`? Do we have to guess what you have changed that leads to this error?

Comment: @t.niese  this sounds interesting, do you have any sources for this? I imagine making an copy would only be useful if you really know what you are doing and in general passing by reference is better.

Comment: In `msgDecripter` your `string decriptedMsg` creates a string with the size `0`, so any `decriptedMsg[i] =` is undefined behavior. Writing `string decriptedMsg = msg` might already resolve the problem. (Using `resize` or setting the size in the constructor would be a better option)

Comment: @t.niese Sorry for not clarifying earlier, but I managed to solve it with your suggestion! A complete oversight on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In `msgDecripter` your `string decriptedMsg` creates a string with the size `0`, so any `decriptedMsg[i] = is` undefined behavior.

In your `msgEncripter` you write `string encriptedMsg = msg;`, and because you create a copy of `mgs` the `encriptedMsg` has the same size.

So either you do `string decriptedMsg = msg`  or `string decriptedMsg = std::string(msg.size(), ' ');`

But a more c++ like approach would be  to use [transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

```
string encriptedMsg = msg;

std::transform(encriptedMsg.begin(), encriptedMsg.end(), encriptedMsg.begin(),
    [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { 
      if( c == ' ') {
        return c;
      } else {
        // ...  your other encrypting logic ... 
      }
    });
```

Or using `msg` as source and an empty string as target and utilize `std::back_inserter`.